# Which one of the following options are correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a non-zero singular matrix. Consider the following
problem: find $X \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that

$(i)AXA = A;$ $(ii)XAX = X $ and $(iii)AX = XA:$

**Part A**.Which of the following statements are true?

a. If a solution to the above problem exists, then $A$ is not nilpotent.

b. If $A $ represents a projection, then the above problem admits a solution.

c. If $n = 2$ and if a solution to the above problem exists, then $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R.$

**Part B.** Suppose $Trace(A)\neq 0$.Show that every such matrix $A$, the problem stated has
a solution given by $$X=\frac{1}{Trace(A)^2}A$$

My Try **Part A.**
If $A$ is not a singular matrix, Then I could have choose $X=A^{-1}$. If $A$ not  singular I have tried this problem for $2 \times 2$ matrix By taking $A=\big [\begin{matrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{matrix}\big]$ and $X=\big [\begin{matrix} 
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22}
\end{matrix}\big].$ But it is time consuming way. Is there any shortcut way to tackle for $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$?

My Try **Part B.**

I really don't know How $X=\frac{1}{Trace(A)^2}A$ is the solution for the given equations

$AXA=A\frac{1}{Trace(A)^2}A A=\frac{1}{Trace(A)^2}A^3$. How this quantity same as $A$?. Only (iii) satisfy this $X$. Please help me.

Comment: The assertion in part B is wrong. Consider $A=diag(1,1,0)$ for instance.

Comment: a) is true: $$A=AXA=AAX=A^2X=A^2XAX=A^3X^2=\ldots=A^{2^n+1}X^{2^n}$$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. If $A$ is nilpotent, $A^m=0$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ so $A=0$ by the equation above choosing $n$ with $2^n+1\geq m$. Contradiction to $A$ non-zero.

Comment: @Mathgeek Hi, this isn't a comment related to this post. I wanted to talk. Can we talk now? :)